# Android Coroutines - How can I wait for two different retrofit calls and wrap both results into one observable?

Tags: android, asynchronous, retrofit

In my view, I need to wait for two different data sets to populate a recycler view.

This is my completely non working function in ViewModel, here it shows what I'm trying to achieve.

```
val resultWrapperLiveData = MutableLiveData<SearchResultWrapper>()

fun searchAandB(query: String) {

    var a: AObject? = null
    var b: BObject? = null

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        launch {
            a = repo.searchA(query = query)
        }
        launch {
            b =  repo.searchB(query = query)
        }
        resultWrapperLiveData.postValue(SearchResultWrapper(a, b))
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a solution. The only problem with this is it waits to start the second api call. It would be better if I can get both of these running at the same time.

```
fun searchAandB(query: String) {

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        val a = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async rt@{
            return@rt repo.searchA(query = query)
        }.await()
        val b = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async rt@{
            return@rt repo.searchB(query = query)
        }.await()

        _searchResultWrapper.postValue(SearchResultWrapper(a, b))
    }
}
```